# How to "compile" an AngularJS app in one html file and keep all sources inline. (grunt)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, build, gruntjs

I develop an AngularJS app, and want to have **all** the sources in one .html file.
I use `grunt` as a buildsystem.
for templates i used `ngtemplates`
Non-AngularJS app, was possible to "compile" with `concat` + `processhtml` grunt tasks.
If i try to do it with the angular-app, page shows me some content of the js files.
Is it possible to keep everything in just one html file?
If yes, show some example please of simple AngularApp + Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the problem was a comments in the angular.js file. The AngularJS-files had comments with examples, that contained `<script>..</script>`parts. If you insert such examples in the html file inline, in the `<script>`tag inside, the closing tag in the comment example, will close the original script tag.
e.g.

```
<script> <---- original script tag
/**
 * example comment.
 * use in this way:
 * <script>example()</script> <---- this will close original tag, and broke js in your html
 */
</script>
```

So i used uglifyjs to **remove all the comments**, and make the js smaller. This **fixed the problem**.

my grunt tasks looks like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('onefile', ['ngtemplates', 'useminPrepare', 'concat:generated', 'uglify:generated', 'cssmin:generated', 'usemin', 'processhtml']);
```

in the HTML the files are commented in such way:

```
  <!-- process:css inline -->
  <!-- build:css styles.min.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- /process -->
```

....

```
  <!-- process:js inline -->
  <!-- build:js app.min.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <!-- endbower -->

  <script src="main-table/main-table.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="templates.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- /process -->
```

`<!-- process:css inline -->` is for [processhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml), to make all code inline.
processhtml uses default commentMarker `build` wich conflicts with usemin commentmarker.
To use it with usemin, define `commentMarker` in the `processhtml` task like:

```
processhtml: {
  options: {
    commentMarker: 'process'
  }
}
```

and for sure, the angular code should be able to be minified, like [Lior Ben Aharon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32593349/2519073) commented.
I used [ngAnnotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ng-annotate) for it.

Answer (score 1):

I know about a way to minify a bunch of js files into one.
Event though it's really easy to minify those files, you need to make them minifiable. it mean's that you should declare function with $injector so it will be "readable" as a minified file.

learn about something called gulp..

```
angular
.module("module")
.controller("ctrl",[
    "$scope",//This is a standard declaration to make a file minifiable.
    function($scope){}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this grunt module https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates

I never used before, but maybe meets your needs.